# How to compile code for the Arduino Due?

Tags: arduino-due, compile, eclipse

I have set up Eclipse to compile for the Arduino Due using all the tools shipped with the Arduino IDE 1.5.6-r2. It compiles without errors, but when uploaded, the Arduino does nothing, and isn't recognized on the computer. It then has to be reset manually using the erase and reset buttons.

There is one static library (ArduinoDueCore) consisting of the Arduino library (`core`), and other code (Atmel found in `lib`). The other Eclipse project is the TestProject. It contains one file blinking an LED on pin 13. All the files from the Arduino library are there.

This is the output from Eclipse compiling the library itself: (excerpt of only one of each type of command)

```
18:31:36 **** Build of configuration Release for project ArduinoDueCore ****
make all
Building file: ../src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.cpp
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Due" -DARDUINO=156 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -D__SAM3X8E__ -Dprintf=iprintf -DF_CPU=84000000L -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x003E -DUSBCON -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/core" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3xa/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x" -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wa,-adhlns="src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.o.lst" -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -w -c -g -fmessage-length=0 --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -nostdlib -MMD -MP -MF"src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.d" -MT"src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.d" -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o "src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.o" "../src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.cpp

Building file: ../src/lib/libsam/source/adc.c
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DARDUINO=156 -DARM_MATH_CM3 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -D__SAM3X8E__ -Dprintf=iprintf -DF_CPU=84000000L -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Due" -DUSB_PID=0x003E -DUSBCON -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/core" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3xa/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x" -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wa,-adhlns="src/lib/libsam/source/adc.o.lst" -w -c -fmessage-length=0 --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -nostdlib -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF"src/lib/libsam/source/adc.d" -MT"src/lib/libsam/source/adc.d" -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o "src/lib/libsam/source/adc.o" "../src/lib/libsam/source/adc.c"
Finished building: ../src/lib/libsam/source/adc.c

Building file: ../src/core/USB/HID.cpp
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Due" -DARDUINO=156 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -D__SAM3X8E__ -Dprintf=iprintf -DF_CPU=84000000L -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x003E -DUSBCON -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/core" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3xa/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x" -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wa,-adhlns="src/core/USB/HID.o.lst" -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -w -c -g -fmessage-length=0 --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -nostdlib -MMD -MP -MF"src/core/USB/HID.d" -MT"src/core/USB/HID.d" -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o "src/core/USB/HID.o" "../src/core/USB/HID.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/core/USB/HID.cpp

Building file: ../src/core/cortex_handlers.c
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DARDUINO=156 -DARM_MATH_CM3 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -D__SAM3X8E__ -Dprintf=iprintf -DF_CPU=84000000L -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Due" -DUSB_PID=0x003E -DUSBCON -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/core" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3xa/include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x" -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wa,-adhlns="src/core/cortex_handlers.o.lst" -w -c -fmessage-length=0 --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -nostdlib -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF"src/core/cortex_handlers.d" -MT"src/core/cortex_handlers.d" -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o "src/core/cortex_handlers.o" "../src/core/cortex_handlers.c"
Finished building: ../src/core/cortex_handlers.c

18:31:39 Build Finished (took 2s.811ms)
```

Here is the project itself:

```
18:33:42 **** Build of configuration Release for project TestProject ****
make all
Building file: ../src/TestProject.cpp
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-g++ -DARDUINO=156 -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Due" -DARDUINO_SAM_DUE -D__SAM3X8E__ -DARDUINO_ARCH_SAM -Dprintf=iprintf -DF_CPU=84000000L -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x003E -DUSBCON -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/core" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/TestProject/src" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/libsam" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/sam3xa/include" -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -c -fmessage-length=0 --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -nostdlib -g -w -MMD -MP -MF"src/TestProject.d" -MT"src/TestProject.d" -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o "src/TestProject.o" "../src/TestProject.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/TestProject.cpp

Building target: TestProject.elf
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -T"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/src/lib/variants/arduino_due_x/linker_scripts/gcc/flash.ld" -L"/home/kim/workspace_juno/ArduinoDueCore/Release" -Wl,-Map,TestProject.map -lm -lgcc  -Wl,--cref -Wl,--check-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align -Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols -Wl,--gc-sections -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -o "TestProject.elf" -Wl,--start-group  ./src/TestProject.o   -lArduinoDueCore -Wl,--end-group
Finished building target: TestProject.elf

make --no-print-directory post-build
/home/kim/arduino-1.5.6-r2/hardware/tools/g++_arm_none_eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary TestProject.elf TestProject.bin

Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GNU Create Listing
arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S TestProject.elf > "TestProject.lst"
Finished building: TestProject.lst

Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GNU Print Size
arm-none-eabi-size  --format=berkeley TestProject.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  10396      24    1188   11608    2d58 TestProject.elf
Finished building: TestProject.siz


18:33:43 Build Finished (took 308ms)
```

Here is the upload command: (removed `readWord`, `go`, `write` and `writeWord` lines)

```
-i -d --port=ttyACM0 -U true -e -w -v -b ${project_loc}/Release/${project_name}.bin -R

Set binary mode
chipId=0x285e0a60
Connected at 921600 baud
Erase flash
Write 10420 bytes to flash

[                              ] 0% (0/41 pages)
[=======                       ] 24% (10/41 pages)
[==============                ] 48% (20/41 pages)
[=====================         ] 73% (30/41 pages)
[============================= ] 97% (40/41 pages)
[==============================] 100% (41/41 pages)
Verify 10420 bytes of flash

[                              ] 0% (0/41 pages)
[=======                       ] 24% (10/41 pages)
[==============                ] 48% (20/41 pages)
[=====================         ] 73% (30/41 pages)
[============================= ] 97% (40/41 pages)
[==============================] 100% (41/41 pages)
Verify successful
Set boot flash true
Device       : ATSAM3X8
Chip ID      : 285e0a60
version()=v1.1 Dec 15 2010 19:25:04
Version      : v1.1 Dec 15 2010 19:25:04
Address      : 524288
Pages        : 2048
Page Size    : 256 bytes
Total Size   : 512KB
Planes       : 2
Lock Regions : 32
Locked       : none
Security     : false
Boot Flash   : true
CPU reset.
```

TestProject.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"

void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(950);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell if it works when you build and upload the program from Arduino IDE instead of Eclipse?

Comment: @jfpoilpret It works from the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Only the `#include "Arduino.h"` line is unnecessary.

Comment: How did you setup eclipse for Arduino, do you use http://eclipse.baeyens.it/ plugin?

Comment: @jfpoilpret I'm using GNU ARM Eclipse plugin version 0.5.4 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse/files/Current%20Releases/0.5.4/) It is set up with the Sourcery Lite toolchain. All the build settings are reflected in the terminal output.

Comment: I used this guide as a starting point, and added preprocessor variables to make it compile successfully.
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,135403.0.html

By following the guide, it worked using Arduino 1.5.1, however it did not support all of the Arduino API...

Comment: Then the next important question is "where is `main()` defined?"

Comment: @jfpoilpret It is defined inside of the Arduino Library. It resides inside `ArduinoDueCore->src->core->main.cpp`.

Comment: OK; in your situation, I would try to compare the output (console and files) of Arduino IDE 1.5 and Eclipse, in order to spot any difference; each found difference is a potential reason of failure. Then analysing each difference can help you find the root cause for it. Sorry, I can't help more, I don't have a DUE available.

Comment: @jfpoilpret That is what I've tried. All the differences I know how to "fix" are "fixed". The problem is that the Arduino IDE uses a precompiled library (I believe) for some operations. I know very little about C/C++, as I've mostly interpreted languages. I'll try and see if I can make the Arduino IDE compile everything itself by deleting the compiled library (`l*\.a`?)

Comment: If I were you, I would rather try http://eclipse.baeyens.it/ (I already use it for UNO boards). It works well, and there is a version for Arduino IDE 1.5 also; that may be your best option?

Comment: @jfpoilpret Does it work for Arduino 1.5.6-r2? The problem with 1.5.1 was that the API wasn't fully developed for the ARM series.

Comment: It is not mentioned; the latest *mentioned* supported IDE is 1.5.5; I guess that does not mean it won't work with 1.5.6, but you'll have to check it by yourself I think.

Comment: @jfpoilpret The reason why I wanted to do it "myself" is because I want to learn how to use the Atmel ARM series step by step. But I suppose Arduino have modified everything so much that it's not like communicating with the real chip anymore. The master branch BOSSA doesn't work on the native port, which I thought was connected directly to the chip... I'll learn how to program it using a book instead.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Now I've set up Baeyens.it. It only works half way. Yes, it uploads the code, but it only starts running after pressing the RESET button manually. Additionally it needs to be erased and reset to listen for new code. The RXTX-library doesn't work, and even triggers a Linux system error. I'll just stick to the Arduino IDE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 1.5.6-r2 with Eclipse cause the Due to hung in Default_Handler function after entering main and polling a few times for the next SysTick gettin passed.

Some weak symbol declarations are done twice (i.e. the SysTick_Handler function definitions). They appear to overwrite each others weak alias depending on the link time usage of the objects. All declarations (not only the failing SysTick_Hanlder) from cortex_handler.c are getting overwritten by weak symbol redeclaration inside startup_sam3xa.c.

This commit seems to already address a weak symbol definition problem.
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/commit/65f00a69c74ca0def8d7f1d7597327945a04a33f

For now, to fix it. Just comment out the part in startup_sam3xa.c with the weak symbol declaration regarding the vectors. Lines 53 to 129.

It should also work to just remove the file completely.
The startup handler code and vector map should be provided by gcc arm built-in libraries instead.